# How do I create a Docker image from a container without configuration changes?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am aware of two ways of creating Docker images:

1. Build the image using a Dockerfile
2. Use [`docker commit <container_id>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) against a running container with changes.

I find changing a Dockerfile each time I need image changes to be awfully inconvenient.
Instead I have taken to launching ephemeral containers with `docker run`, installing packages I need on the fly with sudo, then committing the image.

I didn't realize however there is a footgun involved in this approach, especially if you frequently use and switch up [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) hacks. I launch containers with changing bind mounts, environment variables, differing networks, etc. A lot of that seems to be considered part of the configuration of the container, and is committed in [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) alongside actual filesystem changes.

For example if you do:

```sh
docker run --env FOO=BAR --name container_name ubuntu:focal
docker commit container_name new_image
docker run -it new_image
echo $FOO
```

You will see that the env variable FOO is now a part of new_image.

This creates some awfully confusing situations, as I consider arguments to [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) to be as [ephemeral](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#create-ephemeral-containers) as the container it creates. I am only concerned about persisting package installs.

> I would like to commit *just* the actual image, just the file system changes.
> Is there any way to do that?

Comment: The way to go is as you said to write a Dockerfile. Why do you find it inconvenient? It should be roughly just adding some `RUN ...` directives similar to what you do manually when running the initial container.

Comment: This has been answered in another thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952572/how-to-remove-an-env-setting-from-a-docker-image/39684436

Answer (score 1):

You could try giving [`docker commit --change`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#commit-a-container-with-new-configurations) a try.

```
docker run --env FOO=BAR <image>
docker commit --change "ENV FOO=SETVALUE" <container_from_image> <new_image_tagged_from_state_of_container>
```

Please note that docker's engine specifies that [*"[If the operator] names an environment variable without specifying a value, then the current value of the named variable is propagated into the container’s environment"*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#environment-variables) so you'll need to set the environment variable to something such as `SETVALUE`
an environment variable without specifying a value, the current value of the named variable on the host is propagated into the container's environment

Answer (score 0):

Share us an example of your recurring "image changes". I think your problem is not with docker, is with the architecture of your application.

- Data changes should be handled using a database not  the file system.
- Source code changes, should be managed with a git repository and the respective new build, generating a new image version ready to be deployed
- Infrastructure changes should be ... **That's what Docker was created for.** You should modify the Dockerfile, push the changes, build a new image, etc
- Configurations should be managed with environment variables manually injected at docker run or using some external  service like consul, configurator, etc
- If your application needs to upload or download files like images, reports, etc, you should use a specialized service like aws s3, gcp Filestore, some open source, etc

As you can see, you don't need a huge native backup with docker commit.

Answer (score 0):

## Buildah

> This creates some awfully confusing situations, as I consider arguments to docker run to be as ephemeral as the container it creates. I am only concerned about persisting package installs.

Sure does. Don't use docker. =) Docker is just one method of creating an image. It blurs the line between and online (hot container) and offline build process. Instead try `buildah`, which works with any shell. No dockerfile needed, also runs rootless. Try the below with `buildah unshare ./image.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Call this script image.sh
# Invoke as regular user with `buildah unshare ./image.sh`
ctr=$(buildah from alpine:3)
mnt=$(buildah mount "$ctr")

echo "Created offline container $ctr"
echo "Got mount $mnt"

# write/copy/move directly into $mnt
echo "Write directly into mount" > "$mnt/foo.txt"

temp=$(mktemp)
echo "Created temp $temp"
echo foo > "$temp"
mv "$temp" "$mnt/bar"

echo "No container running"

buildah run "$ctr" /bin/sh <<-EOF
  echo "Hello from inside container.";
  apk update;
  apk add podman;
  echo 42 > baz;
EOF

buildah config                     \
  --author "Joe Doe <foo@bar.com>" \
  --label "apples=oranges"         \
  --env "foo=bar"                  \
  "$ctr";

buildah commit "$ctr" mynewimage
```

You can see what that includes

```
podman run -i mynewimage /bin/sh <<-"EOF"
  echo -e "\nfoo:"
  cat foo

  echo -e "\nbar:"
  cat bar

  echo -e "\nbaz:"
  cat baz

  echo -e "\nenv"
  env
EOF
```